# Append row to different tbody on tabbed pane

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

```
        var $this = $(this);
        var elem = $('#groupRequest-' + data);
        var elemCopy = $('#groupRequest-' + data);
        if (elem.length != 0) {
            elem.toggle("highlight", {}, 1000);
            elem.hide("slow");
            $('#accountGroupHistory').append(elemCopy);
```

---

var elem is selecting a row based on the row number it receives in the data

```
<tbody id="accountGroupHistory">

        @foreach (GroupRequest item in Model.Where(i => i.GroupStatusId > 1))
        {
            <tr class="row " id="groupRequest-@item.GroupRequestId" data-refresh-url="">

                <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UpdatedDate)</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UpdatedBy.FullName)</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CreatedDate)</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">@item.GroupRequestStatus.Label</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.FinalAccountGroup.Label)</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Entity.Label)</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.OrginAccount.Name)</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CreatedBy.FullName)</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CreatedBy.AmarisOfficeExtension.Label)</td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

I want this to append elemcopy to the bottom of another tbodyon a tabbed pane

When a row is modified I want to hide the row in that table and append that row onto another table.

Comment: can u also share the generated html?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wcA0KPA.png

Comment: Right now `elemCopy` is not a copy, but a reference to the same object as `elem`. If you append `elemCopy` to another table, it will removed from the first one. So it should be doing what you want if i understood it correctly? What do you have problems with?

Comment: @Andy It gets removed from the first table but on the second table it doesn't get appended. I can append text to the bottom of the table but the row won't append.

Comment: You are hiding `elem`, which, as said, is the same element. It's probably appended correctly but hidden.

Comment: yeah as @Andy suggested. elem is already hidden. try removing the elem.hide() and see if it works.